# Kill process using Python /F flag

Tags: python

I'm wondering how to do this in python.

```
C:\>Taskkill /IM program.exe /F
```

What I have so far is this. I just don't know how to add the  `/F` flag

```
comm = "taskkill /im " + myprogram
os.system(comm)
```

Comment: The same way you added the rest: `comm = comm + " /F"`. You are just building up a string that the underlying shell will parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this code below works :

```
comm = “{} {}“.format(comm, " /F")
```